# Cypress, look for multiple parameters like ID and Class

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

I was wondering if it's possible to search by multiple parameters in cypress, for example ID and Class

```
it('find button',function(){ 
   cy.get('#button_id, .button-class').click()
})
```

is this something that is achievable???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can directly use `#button_id.button-class`

```js
it('find button',function(){ 
   cy.get('#button_id.button-class').click()
})
```

In my local I cross created this element:

```html
<div class="titleclass" id="titleid">Apple</div>
```

And in the test runner if you could see, I was able to use both class and id `cy.get('#titleid.titleclass')` and successfully get the element.

[image: Test runner screenshot]

Comment: thanks Alapan, but i just attempted that and it didn't work :( 
Error:     AssertionError: Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: `#user_username.sing-in-field`, but never found it

Comment: Can you add the exact html, it would give more clarity and help to come up with a answer, because the above works correctly. Also, I could see that for class you have used `sing-in-field`, should it be `sign-in-field`.

Comment: you know what Alapan, I apologize, it was my misspelling. Thank you SO MUCH for the assistance